# Java Resultset does not maintain the changed value when updating Resultset

Tags: java

The essential code for this problem is:

```
Connection con;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;

stmt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);     

rs=stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

rs.updateInt("CUSTOMER_ID", newID);
rs.updateString("NAME", company);
rs.updateString("CITY", city);
rs.updateString("STATE", state);
rs.updateRow();
```

When I change a field and update it, then move to another record and come back to the one I changed, it reverts to what was there before I made the change. If I close and restart the app, then it reflects the change. It seems to commit the change to the underlying database, but not to the result set it self. I tried different result set parameters but `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` and `CONCUR_UPDATABLE` are supposed to be the appropriate ones.

When I hit NEXT or PREVIOUS to go to another record the code is just setting the text fields by grabbing them from the result set. So the result set is just not holding or recognizing the change and the result set updateString and updateInt methods.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Please specify which database and driver you are using. Note that the JDBC specification allows a driver to not propagate changes to the result set itself, hence the methods [`DatabaseMetaData.ownUpdatesAreVisible(int type)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#ownUpdatesAreVisible-int-) (and similar for delete and insert)

Comment: This is using Net Beans and the sample database and driver that comes with it. I was following a tutorial and they said specifically that the resultset will reflect the changes when you navigate away from the changed record and then back again. This tutorial and code is here:

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/update_a_database_record_in_java.html

Answer (score 1):

To determine if the result set can see its own updates call:
[`DatabaseMetaData::ownUpdatesAreVisible`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#ownUpdatesAreVisible-int-).

Check the JDBC specification and your JDBC driver's documentation for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not closed your statement.

Use `stmt.close()` with try catch block.

```
Statement stmt = null;
    try {

    // your code here.
       stmt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
       ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);     

       rs=stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

       rs.updateInt("CUSTOMER_ID", newID);
       rs.updateString("NAME", company);
       rs.updateString("CITY", city);
       rs.updateString("STATE", state);
       rs.updateRow();
       conn.commit(); // this connection commit() method will solve your issue

    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
```

Resource Link:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html
2. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=131026&seqNum=6

Comment: If I close the statement then it generates an error trying to use the resultset.....

Comment: You will close the statement when you finish to use the resultset. After completing all your operation using resultset, you will close the statement. it is the rule. You can follow the first link and check how they use statement closing and connection closing.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, but then nothing has changed while using the resultset. While using the resultset and making a change, the resultset displays the original data in the field and not the changed data when I navigate away and then back again to that record. But it is updating the underlying database as when I close and run again the changed data is shown.

Comment: @valhalla Would you please tell me about your app? In which language it is developed or gui basis what are you using? I hope on that case we can give you exact solution.

Comment: Thanks SkyWalker! I'm using NetBeans and of course Java. The application came from a tutorial in Java at HomeAndLearn.com Java for complete beginners. The url is:

Comment: @valhalla Your learning site actually update the database not view part. You need to use DefaultTableModel on that case and reload needed to show updated table. Follow this tutorial. http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20701077/JTable-cannot-be-refreshed-after-changing-data-in-a-database.html

Comment: I just reloaded the resultset from the database in the update code. Then everything is there. I wish the author of these tutorials at HomandLearn in the United Kingdom would check their work...:) I wrote to them about this but they do not write back....